# Error 3251 on OpenSchema to list current DB users

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have two DB of a same BE, one that is old, and its replacement made from a newer project. Tables and their structure are the same, only data differ.

I'm creating some automated maintenance options available on the FE so other people without any ACCESS knowledge could perform tasks like getting specific records out of the main DB and towards an Archive-dedicated one. For this purpose, I need to check if anybody else than the one user doing the maintenance is connected to the DB. If yes, plainly abort, if not, proceed (For now at least, I will improve things later).

I'm trying to do this verification by listing all active DB users with this OpenSchema query:

```
cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")
```

(cn being an ADODB.Connection object)

But I can't figure why, it returns an error 3251 "Object or provider is not capable of performing requested operation" on the newer DB, while its old self works like a charm (With the same ConnectionString). I could just copy the tables in the working DB manually, but I expect it will cause hidden trouble compared to a clean BE extraction from the ACCDB, without even mentionning any possible human error.

I tried to compare the two DB and spot any difference that could explain the behavior (Checking DB and Project properties one by one, connections both auto and manual, with and without tables, modules, password etc...), but I'm running out of ideas.

Anyone has any idea or hint about what could be causing this? I can provide stripped versions of the two DB if needed (Having anything in it or not give the same results).

Of course if you have another solution to check if a user is the only one using a database and just bypass the OpenSchema method completely, I'm all ears.

**UPDATE 03-10-2018**

Here is the function used to do the verification.

```
Public Function checkMultipleUsers()

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim nbUsers As Integer

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                          "User ID=Admin;" & _
                          "Data Source=\\SERVERPATH\Project_BE.accdb;" & _
                          "Mode=Share Deny None;" & _
                          "Extended Properties="""";" & _
                          "Locale Identifier=1036;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\Access Connectivity Engine;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=""PASSWORD"";" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=True;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;" & _
                          "Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"
    cn.Open

    nbUsers = 0

    ' The user roster is exposed as a provider-specific schema rowset
    ' in the Jet 4.0 OLE DB provider.  You have to use a GUID to
    ' reference the schema, as provider-specific schemas are not
    ' listed in ADO's type library for schema rowsets

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, _
    , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

    While Not rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields(2) = True Then
            nbUsers = nbUsers + 1
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    If nbUsers = 1 Then
        checkMultipleUsers = False
    ElseIf nbUsers > 1 Then
        checkMultipleUsers = True
    Else
        MsgBox ("ACCESS can't determine the number of users. Operation aborted.")
        checkMultipleUsers = 0
    End If

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

I got the ConnectionString parameters mainly from a query of CurrentProject.ConnectionString, but reducing them to those below won't work either so I don't expect them to be the problem.

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                      "Data Source=\\SERVER\Project_BE.accdb;" & _
                      "Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw;" & _
                      "Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\Access Connectivity Engine;" & _
                      "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=""PASSWORD"";"
cn.Open
```

Comment: Huh? `cn` is a connection object and you're using `cn.Connection`? Anyway, you should provide the code opening the connection, including the connection string.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to write cn.OpenSchema. I added the entire function with the ConnectionString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, happens the DB was most likely corrupted, AND probably fucked up something in the RAM for Access to use, because I tried to create an entirely new DB and copy every element of the problematic one into the newer when I encountered the bug and some days after, it didn't work at the time.

What I didn't think of was that we never shut down our computers at work so IT can do maintenance at night, thus the RAM is never entirely flushed from one day to another.

Tried the exact same thing this week, it works like a charm. I guess IT needed to restart all the PCs or we got an electric failure since last time I tried.

So yeah. Thanks Access for these past weeks headaches for literally nothing, and thanks me for not thinking about doing a proper reboot to start anew (Actually got something like that some years ago, a proc would just refuse to launch whatever the file it was in or the way it was called, rebooted computer two days after and it worked like a charm).