# Why does the location of the Access DB influence a VBA connection to it?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, ms-access-2016

I'm scratching my head on this one.

In the following five locations I have copy and pasted the exact same Ms Access DB (.accdb):

- 1: `C:\JunkSaves`
- 2: `C:\Users\...\OneDrive\Desktop\...\Project Tool\DBTransfer`
- 3: `C:\Users\...\OneDrive\Desktop\...\Project Tool\Tool`
- 4: `\\Netork\Server$\...\02_Test and Training Environment`
- 5: `\\Netork\Server$\...\Projects\_Archive`

Now when I run the following code:

```
Private Sub GetUsers()
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set Rs = Nothing
    Set ThisWorkbook.TenantDB = Nothing
    Call DBLookup.ConnectToDB 
    'ThisWorkbook.TenantDB Type = ADODB.Connection
    Set Rs = ThisWorkbook.TenantDB.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")
    ... Do something ...
End Sub
```

If I try to run this script on the DBs located at `2` and `4`, I get the following error at the line `Set Rs = ...`:

[image: Error Description: Run time error 3251]

I'm trying to understand why the Location of the DBs influences the ability for an Excel VBA script to be able to connect?

Here is some additional information for context:

- Before each test, I used Powershell to kill all instances of Excel and Access.
- I can run other queries (ie. Select, Update, ...) in the database no matter the location.
- Links from some research I've done

  - [Error 3251 on OpenSchema to list current DB users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612607/error-3251-on-openschema-to-list-current-db-users)
  - [FIX: OpenSchema Method Generates Error 3251 (195487)](https://ftp.zx.net.nz/pub/archive/ftp.microsoft.com/MISC/KB/en-us/195/487.HTM)
- I copied the Access DB from a location that didn't work to a location that did work and I was still able to run my script without issue.
- VBA Script is being run inside a macro-enabled Excel file.
- Connection String

  `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DbPath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & constants.ToolPassword & ";"`

I'm really hoping someone could shed some light on this issue. Thank you in advance.

New Info: Using the method described at [How to determine who is logged on to a database by using Microsoft Jet UserRoster in Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/determine-who-is-logged-on-to-database) I ran roughly the same script but directly on the MS Access DB and got the same results.

[image: Error from Ms Access VBA Script]
[image: No Error from a different location]

Comment: I would expect you to have issues with 2 and 3 rather than 2 and 4 because OneDrive locations are on Sharepoint.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864673/excel-vba-to-query-ms-access-database-on-sharepoint-with-adodb-not-a-valid-fi

Comment: Sadly No, I have issues with what appear to be random folders.

Comment: @CHill60 also I'm getting a different error than the one experienced by the OP in your link.

Comment: Firstly, I would try adding the problematic paths in Access Trusted locations (`Options` ->  `Trust Center` -> `Trust Center Settings...` - `Trusted Locations`) and try again. It may be a matter of security, Access guessing that the respective paths may have problems, from this point of view... Or not. :)

Comment: @FaneDuru you might be onto something but I don't have permission to change these settings on my work laptop.

Comment: Then, since the paths in discussion are form the local network, ask the IT administrator to do it, or to give you the necessary permissions. But, can't you really acces Access Options?  Or only Trust Center settings?

Comment: I can but I can't add a folder to the `Trusted Locations`. Also none of the working locations seem to be a subfolder of the list of valid locations.

Comment: That's why you should place them in that list...